# Female main character (?) moves to new state & finds herself in the middle of spiritual war between aura vampires and aura manipulators

Tags: story-identification

I read this close to 20 years ago(mid 90's).  The two main parts of the story I remember are a school hockey game being influenced by aura manipulators (both good + bad).  Another character is able to enclose his aura in himself when a vampire tries to feed on him.

There were also gold aura people popping up throughout the story which I think turned out to be aliens/enlightened people(?)